# Dancer2 Auth::Extensible Not Accepting Hashed Password

Tags: postgresql, perl, authentication, sha, dancer

I've generated a SHA-1 hash using Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase with the following code:

```
get '/generate' => {
    my $phrase = passphrase('my_password')->generate({ algorithm => 'SHA-1'});
    return $phrase->rfc2307();
};
```

The result looks something like this:

```
{SSHA}+2Dro1/ntPchT93mgvYMKGjdzy+XKXK1agsG3//hKuLNrQAK
```

and that's what I store in my PostgreSQL database.

I'm using Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible as my login solution, but I've yet to get it to work with encrypted passwords. I put a test account into my database where username='test' and password='test', and that works fine. But username='test2' and password='{SSHA}+2Dro1/ntPchT93mgvYMKGjdzy+XKXK1agsG3//hKuLNrQAK' doesn't work. The login page just silently fails and reloads.

I turned on DBI_TRACE and don't seen much difference between the two except that the account with the plain text password returns this:

```
[glm::App:3515] debug @2016-05-10 21:02:23> users accepted user test in /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Dancer2/Core/Route.pm l. 137
```

and the account with the encrypted password returns this:

```
[glm::App:3523] core @2016-05-10 21:04:21> looking for get /login in /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Dancer2/Core/App.pm l. 1210
[glm::App:3523] core @2016-05-10 21:04:21> Entering hook core.app.before_request in (eval 62) l. 1
[glm::App:3523] core @2016-05-10 21:04:21> Entering hook core.app.after_request in (eval 62) l. 1
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2016:21:04:21 +0100] "POST /login?return_url=%2F     HTTP/1.1" 401 383 "http://localhost:5000/login?return_url=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but [the CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/~hornburg/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-0.502/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Auth/Extensible.pm) doesn't detail how to handle encrypted passwords. It just says it will be easy. I guess I'm reading that as "encrypted passwords will be handled automagically." What am I missing?

**Config**

This is the relevant portion of my config

```
plugins: 
 Auth::Extensible:
   realms:
      users:
       provider: 'Database'
 Database:
  dsn: 'dbi:Pg:service=test'
```

**App.pm**

Below is what I'm doing in the App.pm. You can see that I'm just trying to require a login for the home page. Maybe I need some '/login' code?

```
package glm::App;

use Dancer2;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Database;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase;

use Template;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => require_login sub {
    my $sth = database->prepare('SELECT name FROM product', { RaiseError => 1 });
    $sth->execute();

    template 'create_list', {
        'products' => $sth->fetchall_hashref('name'),
    };
};

get '/generate'=> sub {
    my $phrase = passphrase('my_password')->generate({ algorithm => 'SHA-1' });
    return $phrase->rfc2307(); # right now I just manually copy and paste this into the database
};
```

My database follows the [suggested schema](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database#SUGGESTED-SCHEMA) for users, passwords, and roles.

Maybe the only other relevant bit of information I can think of is that if I use an encryption scheme not recognized by Digest, I get an error from Digest.pm. That would seem to indicate that it's recognizing the hashed password and trying to decrypt it, but for whatever reason it's just not working. Or it's working and redirecting back to the home page... But why doesn't it do that with 'test,test'?

Comment: Can you post your code please? If the password looks like an encrypted password, then DPAE uses ```Crypt::SaltedHash``` to check it, so it should Just Work. The code for that is here: https://metacpan.org/source/HORNBURG/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-Extensible-0.502/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Auth/Extensible/Provider/Base.pm#L88

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I've added everything that I think might be relevant. Let me know if there's anything else that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You're using two different methods for hashing, so the generated hashes are incompatible.

[Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database](https://metacpan.org/source/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Base#L99) uses Crypt::SaltedHash:

```
sub encrypt_password {
    my ($self, $password, $algorithm) = @_;
    $algorithm ||= 'SHA-1';
    my $crypt = Crypt::SaltedHash->new(algorithm => $algorithm);
    $crypt->add($password);
    $crypt->generate;
}
```

This generates a hash like:

```
{SSHA}qTEaPf8KRPt6XBQXIlQhlWstgBz64coW
```

Compare that to what you got from Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase:

```
{SSHA}+2Dro1/ntPchT93mgvYMKGjdzy+XKXK1agsG3//hKuLNrQAK
```

Notice that the lengths are different. Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase uses a 16-byte salt by default, while Crypt::SaltedHash uses a 4-byte salt.

---

Although you *could* tell Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase to use a 4-byte salt, it's much easier to just use Crypt::SaltedHash everywhere. The Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible#DESCRIPTION) explains how to do this:

> A simple script called `generate-crypted-password` to generate RFC2307-style hashed passwords is included, or you can use Crypt::SaltedHash yourself to do so, or use the `slappasswd` utility if you have it installed.

For example:

```
$ generate-crypted-password 
Enter plain-text password ?> foo
Result: {SSHA}zdXPS0QqxyKlzXwHxjJ3rsU19Td4ABzW
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used `generate-crypted-password` as you suggested and that did the trick. I didn't pick up on the difference in length at all. Thank you, thank you, thank you!